# Size drastically increased when images converted to hdf5 format

Tags: deep-learning, image-preprocessing, kaggle

I converted [Kaggle Dog vs Cat](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data?select=train.zip) dataset from image to hdf5 format, in order to fasten the learning time. To my surprise, **540MB** training data converted to  more than **30GB** of data in hdf5 file format. Why is this so. Also I have not much space in my laptop, is there any other method to fasten my deep learning process without consuming too much space.

Comment: You probably didn't use any compression

Comment: How much storage your data takes does not necessarily correlate with how fast your training takes. Also, for image data, it is highly discouraged to try to load all data in memory anyway due to their size.